# How to save types of variables to a file using Frama-C

Tags: c, static-analysis, frama-c

I am trying to print types of variables in C program using Frama-C.
I found that this information is represented in the GUI as in the figure below. However, I cannot found a way to output this information to a file. Could you please suggest me the way to perform this task with Frama-c?
[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You should be able to copy the text from the "Information" tab to the clipboard and save it in a file.

Comment: I want to get the types of all variables in C program and save it to a file, then use this information to analyze the source code later. Hence, I expect an automated way to perform this task.

Comment: Then I'm out, I don't know Frama-C.

Comment: thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no direct solutions from the command line. However, this can be very easily done with a simple script such as (not tested)

```ml
let print_type () =
  Ast.compute();
  Globals.Vars.iter
   (fun v _ ->
     Format.printf "Variable %a: %a@."
     Cil_datatype.Varinfo.pretty v
     Cil_datatype.Typ.pretty v.vtype)

let () = Db.Main.extend print_type
```

which can be launched with `frama-c -load-script <my_script.ml> <other args including source files>`

More information on scripting Frama-C (including an extensive tutorial) is available in the [developer manual](https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-plugin-development-guide.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I understand, your script only handles global variables. Is it possible to handle other types of variables, including external, argument, and local variables?

Comment: Sure, you can basically inspect any node in Frama-C Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) by writing an appropriate visitor. Section 2.4.1 of the developer manual gives an example of a very simple visitor, and the mechanism is detailed in section 4.17. `Db.Main.extend (fun () -> Visitor.visitFramacFileSameGlobals (object method! vvdec v = Format.printf "Variable %a: %a@." Cil_datatype.Varinfo.pretty v Cil_datatype.Typ.pretty v.vtype; Cil.DoChildren end)` (again not tested) should do the trick, but comments are not well suited for writing code. Feel free to open a new question if you have troubles.